# Drag div inside div (child > parent)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, containers, drag

I tried a lot of things, but I can't get it work:

I have a div inside a div, and want the child (= inner div) be draggable only within the parent.
The thing is: The child is bigger than the parent and everytime I want to drag the child within the parent, it always snaps immediately at the side of the parent, because it does not fit in.

Any solution is appreciated!!

Here is the project:

http://jsfiddle.net/yc5f9ym6/

And here is what I want to make:

http://jsfiddle.net/WBv9r/1/light

HTML

```
    <div class="nhood">
        <div class="image"></div>
    </div>


</div>
```

CSS

```
.image {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    border: solid 5px black;
    background: green;
    cursor:move;
}



.nhood {
    margin: 100px auto 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
}
```

JS

```
$(".image").draggable(
    {
        containment: ".nhood"
    });
```

Thanks!

Clarification:
The child should have the same borders as the parents' borders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you let yout question more clear, what you need is to change the `containment` option.

You need to use the Array option, and define the box size to where the draggable can be moved:

```
var draggable = $('.image');
var viewport = $('.nhood');
var viewportOffset = viewport.offset();
var box = 
    {
        x1: viewportOffset.left + (viewport.outerWidth() - draggable.outerWidth()),
        y1: viewportOffset.top + (viewport.outerHeight() - draggable.outerHeight()),
        x2: viewportOffset.left,
        y2: viewportOffset.top
    };

$(".image").draggable(
        {
            containment: [box.x1, box.y1, box.x2, box.y2 ]
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yc5f9ym6/5/

The trick is on the box coordinates, note `x1` and `y1` are the current position minus the space necessary to show the bottom or right edges of child in the parent.

Comment: Thank you, but I want the child borders be the parents borders.

Comment: do you mean the child size should adapt to its position? Otherwise I can't see what you're asking.

Comment: You should have posted that link in your question, now it works like that,

Comment: Thank you, I added the link to the question.

This solved my problem! Thanks a lot!